# Filter Pipeline Runs by pipeline parameters in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a pipeline on Azure Data Factory that runs more than one time per day.

Every pipeline run has different parameters.

When we need to see the pipeline runs status on Pipeline runs report, we can filter pipeline runs by time range, pipeline name, runs, and status.

Our question is can we filter pipeline runs by parameters that passed to the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively you **cannot filter pipeline runs by pipeline** **[parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually#:%7E:text=Parameters,name/value%20pairs)**, you can just list them as one of the columns in the report.

[image]

[image]

Meanwhile you can use **Triggered By** to filter pipeline runs based on **Trigger Parameters**.

By default some are not listed, you can edit columns to see them.

[image]

Add column or select:

[image]

Filter based on different parameters you have created. Have shown one as an example

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to show a parameter.
Before, I was checking parameters one by one.